# How to read first n number of columns into a SAS dataset?

Tags: sas

My raw datafiles is a simple comma delimited file that contains 10 columns. I know there must be a way of importing only 'say 3 columns using `missover` OR `ls` ?

Sure, I can import all file and drop uneeded varialbes, however, how can I use
`infile missover=3`

OR

`infile ls=3`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I guess as SAS has to read all the data from a delimited file - it has to read every byte from beginning to end to 1) process the column delimiters, and 2) determine the obs delimiters (CR&LF characters) - DROPing the unneeded columns wouldn't be much of an overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read only the first n fields you can just list those in your input statement.

If the columns you need are more to the right you will need to list in your input all the columns before those you need and up to the last column you need.

`MISSOVER` does not take `=n` and it tells sas to go to the next record and start reading into the first variable of the input statement if it doesn't find enough columns and not look for the last columns in the following record.

e.g

```
file is like this

 a1,b1,c1
 a2,b2,c3,d2

data test;
   infile "myfile" dlm="," dsd /*2 cosecutive delimiters are not considered as one*/ missover;
        input
        a $
        b $
        c $
        d $
        ;
    run;

will result in a dataset:
a  b  c  d
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2 d2

    data test;
    infile "myfile" dlm="," dsd /*2 cosecutive delimiters are not considered as one*/ ;
    input
    a $
    b $
    c $
    d $
    ;
    run;

will result in a dataset:
a  b  c  d
a1 b1 c1 a2
```